# Matplotlib: Color bar on contour without striping

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib, I'm looking to create an inset color bar to show the scale of my contour plot, but when I create the contour using contour, the color bar has white stripes running through it, whereas when I use contourf, the colorbar has the proper "smooth" appearance:

[image: Contour comparisons]

How can I get that nice smooth colorbar from the filled contour on my normal contour plot? I'd also be OK with a filled contour where the zero-level can be set to white, I imagine.

Here is code to generate this example:

```
from numpy import linspace, outer, exp
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, gca, clf, subplots_adjust, subplot
from matplotlib.pyplot import contour, contourf, colorbar, xlim, ylim, title
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes

# Make some data to plot - 2D gaussians
x = linspace(0, 5, 100)
y = linspace(0, 5, 100)
g1 = exp(-((x-0.75)/0.2)**2)
g2 = exp(-((y-4.25)/0.1)**2)
g3 = exp(-((x-3.5)/0.15)**2)
g4 = exp(-((y-1.75)/0.05)**2)
z = outer(g1, g2) + outer(g3, g4) 

figure(1, figsize=(13,6.5))
clf()

# Create a contour and a contourf
for ii in range(0, 2):
    subplot(1, 2, ii+1)

    if ii == 0:
        ca = contour(x, y, z, 125)
        title('Contour')
    else:
        ca = contourf(x, y, z, 125)
        title('Filled Contour')

    xlim(0, 5)
    ylim(0, 5)

    # Make the axis labels
    yt = text(-0.35, 2.55, 'y (units)', rotation='vertical', size=14);
    xt = text(2.45, -0.4, 'x (units)', rotation='horizontal', size=14)

    # Add color bar
    ains = inset_axes(gca(), width='5%', height='60%', loc=2)
    colorbar(ca, cax=ains, orientation='vertical', ticks=[round(xx*10.0)/10.0 for xx in linspace(0, 1)])

    if ii ==1:
        ains.tick_params(axis='y', colors='#CCCCCC') 

subplots_adjust(left=0.05, bottom=0.09, right=0.98, top=0.94, wspace=0.12, hspace=0.2)

show()
```

**Edit**: I realize now that at the lower resolution, the white striping behavior is hard to distinguish from some light transparency. Here's an example with only 30 contour lines which makes the problem more obvious:

[image: FewContours]

**Edit 2**: While I am still interested in figuring out how to do this in the general general case (like if there's negative values), in my specific case, I have determined that I can effectively create something that looks like what I want by simply setting the levels of a filled contour to start above the zero-level:

`ca = contourf(x, y, z, levels=linspace(0.05, 1, 125))`

Which basically looks like what I want:

[image: KlugeContours]

Comment: Is there still an issue? If you figured out the problem, can you answer and close question?

Comment: I solved my specific issue by making something that looks like what I want, but the general issue is still there. If my data had any negative values or if I wanted to see actual contour lines, then my solution wouldn't work, so while it's not urgent for me, it's still a problem and needs a real solution.

Comment: The way that color bar for `contour` works is to draw a single line in the color bar for each line. Changing this will involve re-writing how  `colorbar` deals with contour plots.

Answer (score 4):

A simple hack is to set the thickness of the lines in the colorbar to some higher value.
E.g. storing the colorbar object as `cb` and adding the following lines to your example

```
for line in cb.lines: 
   line.set_linewidth(3)
```

gives
[image]